# angularjs infinitescroll ng-repeat issue

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, ng-grid, celltemplate

i have a div implementing infinite-scroll which is placed in a partial HTML page.this div has a

implementation within it this ul is implementing ng-repeat for the items got through infinite-scrolln function implemented in a factory.this function is working fine on each scroll.but my

is not getting rendered

here is that html

```
      <div ng-controller="studentCareerList">              
              <div  infinite-scroll="list.nextPage(list.index,limit,'engineer')"  infinite-scroll-disabled='list.stopscript' >                      
                  <ul class="selectMajor relatedCareer " ng-repeat="item in myData" >                         
                      <li class="check">
                          <input type="checkbox" id="check5" class="css-checkbox" /><label class="css-label" for="check5"></label></li>
                      <li class="icon"><span class="icon30 greenSetting" ></span></li>
                      <li class="name">
                          <p>{{item.Name}}</p>
                      </li>
                      <li class="description">{{item.Description}}</li>
                      <li class="remaining">{{item.EarningsAnnual}}</li>
                      <li class="like"><span class="greyLike"></span></li>
                  </ul>
                  <div class="message" style="text-align: center;" ng-show="list.noRecordTrigger">
                      <span class="infoIcon"></span>
                      <span>No record found.</span>
                  </div>

              </div>


          <div><span ng-show="list.busy">Loading please wait...</span></div>
      </div>
```

Comment: Can you post the directive and your controller?

Comment: What is not rendered?

Comment: my <ul><li> section is not rendered

Comment: I simply took the <ul><li> section out of infinite-scroll div and it started working.Don't know why this happened.if someone knows plz share it.  Thanks